# Azure web site not recognizing perfectly my Domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have azure websites like

`synapsit.azurewebsites.net` deployed on azure I have domain name `www.synapsit.no` which is nothing but my main azure website.

I mapped my domain name with azure webapp's IP address. but when I put `synapsit.no` in to browser it will redirected to `synapsit.azurewebsites.net`. Why it is happening I dont know.

I tried many things like CNAME configuration Manage domain but did not able to achieve this. Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure you have created a CNAME and not a forwarder? Using a CNAME will preserve the right URL and is the right way to do this.

Comment: Do you have references in your web.config to the Azure website name rather than www.synapsit.no?  Maybe in a permission/location tag or maybe you have a redirect somewhere?